# Why can't inner classes declare static members?

Tags: java, inner-classes

The Java Tutorial says that since an inner class is associated with an instance of the enclosing class, it (the inner class) cannot define any static members itself.

It's interesting for me why can't inner classes declare static members for instance, some `private static` field, which the instance of this inner class could possibly share with the other instances of the same inner class? is this just an implementation of things in Java that has to be taken for granted or something else?

Comment: I don't know Java, and it's a surprise for me that an inner class is associated with an _instance_ of the outer class

Comment: @Armen: A non-static inner class is really like a "normal" inner class with an implicit pointer to an outer class instance.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan a few hours ago that was a surprise for me as well =) now i'm asking some questins here to fill in the gaps in understanding Java concepts...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically just an arbitrary decision.  there's no reason it *couldn't* be supported, but there is also not really any good reason *to* support it.  just declare the static field in the outer class.

also, that quote may not be entirely correct: i believe you can declare a static serialVersionUID in an inner class.

Update, sounds like this is now possible as of [Java 16](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/language/java-language-changes.html#GUID-EE327F97-BF08-46D2-8426-085CBE585797).

Comment: Yep, it's a compiler restriction, not something inherent in the JVM.  Inner classes are a major kluge, and there's really no distinction between inner and outer at the JVM level.

Comment: More specifically, you can declare static fields that are compile-time constants, which a serialVersionUID has to be.

Comment: Isn't "put your variable in the class that logically owns it" a good reason to support it?

Comment: @EricLindauer - dunno, ask the designers of the java language spec.

Comment: Isn't encapsulation a good reason to allow it? I prefer to keep my fields as close to the place I use them as possible, not polluting the outer class.

Comment: @HummelingEngineering - as i said in my previous comment, i'm not defending the decision and i'm certainly not responsible for it.  i'm just the messenger.  your question should be directed to the java language designers.

Comment: @jtahlborn - my comment wasn't directed at you, it's just contemplating on Java's design.

Comment: Looks like ten years later they found a reason to support it: [Java Language Changes for Java SE 16: Record Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/language/java-language-changes.html#GUID-EE327F97-BF08-46D2-8426-085CBE585797)

Comment: @jla - ha! nice to have that arbitrary decision reversed!

Answer (score 10):

Because the [Java Language Specification says so](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly
>   declared static. Inner classes may not declare static initializers
>   (§8.7) or member interfaces. Inner classes may not declare static
>   members, unless they are compile-time constant fields (§15.28).

As for *why* it was specified that way, I do not know. My guess is that inner classes were designed as small helper classes that should be very limited in complexity.

Comment: Does this restriction hold for *static* inner classes?

Comment: @pst: By definition there is no such thing as a static inner class. See the first sentence I cited.

Comment: Err, a *static nested class*.

Comment: @pst: If you follow the link to the spec you'll find that it explicitly says "Nested classes that are not inner classes may declare static members freely, in accordance with the usual rules of the Java programming language."

Comment: up-vote for clarity on this issue. Despite the static keyword they really are not "Static"

Answer (score 4):

Why can't inner classes declare static members?

The inner class is contained in the instance area of ​​the outer class. Therefore, within the inner class, it is not allowed to declare static members. On the other hand, the static inner class is contained in the static area of ​​the outer class. Thus, it is only allowed to declare static members and not instance members.

[image: image >> two areas inside outer class]

Answer (score 4):

As of Java 17, non-static inner classes *can* declare static members. The member is for the entire class. It doesn't matter which object instantiated it. Here is a sample program to demonstrate that.

```
public class Demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Person fred = new Person("Fred");
      Person.Property p1 = fred.new Property("last name", "Flintstone");
      Person wilma = new Person("Wilma");
      Person.Property p2 = wilma.new Property("spouse", fred);
      System.out.println(p1);
      System.out.println(p2);
   }
}

class Person {
   private String name;
   public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
   public class Property {
      private static int count; // Only since Java 17
      private String name;
      private Object value;
      public Property(String name, Object value) {
         count++;
         this.name = name; 
         this.value = value;
      }
      public String toString() { return "I am a property (one of " + count + ") of " + Person.this.name + " with name " + name + " and value " + value; }
   }
}
```

The output:

```
I am a property (one of 2) of Fred with name last name and value Flintstone
I am a property (one of 2) of Wilma with name spouse and value Person@4e25154f
```

The point is `one of 2`. One of the `Property` objects belongs to `fred`, the other to `wilma`. The static variable `count` doesn't care. The `Person.Property` class has a single static `count` variable.

Answer (score 0):

An inner `class` may not declare `static` fields unless they are compile-time constants. Hence, if you declare the `static` field as `final` it will work.

```
class Foo {
    class Test {
       final static int i = 10;
    }
}
```

will compile and run perfectly

`static` fields can only be declared in `static` or top-level types. Hence, a (pure) `static` variable can be declared only in a `static` `class`.

Answer (score -2):

That would result in a conflict of interest to have a static member variable inside an inner class. Generally speaking, an inner class needs to have an object instance of the outer or enclosing class before it may be instantiated. A static member variable suggests that you don't even need an object instance for that particular class, the inner class in this case, but that class the inner class is dependent upon and can only coexist along with the outer class instance. Do you see where the conflict of interest arises in the argument? However, you can make a static member variable inside an inner class by declaring the inner class as static which means the inner class no longer needs to coexist with an outer class object.

```
public class A {

   public static class B {

       private static JPanel myJPanel;

   }

}
```

Comment: Why would B declaring a static member somehow mean it doesn't depend on the enclosing instance of A? These seem orthogonal.

Comment: @EVAC-Q8R i think i understand what you mean. in order to access the static member of the inner class it would be something like OuterClass**InstanceName**.InnerClass**TypeName**.innerClassStaticMemberName which would be definetly an uncomfortable mix. On the other hand it's still possible to access static members thru an instance in Java (which is not required usually). So why not have this construction like this then: OuterClass**InstanceName**.new InnerClass().innerClassStaticMemberName

Comment: @ Sean - I declared the inner class B "static" as opposed to "public class B" which means it no longer needs an enclosing object in order to instantiate it... not because of the static JPanel myJPanel instance.