# inner classes cannot have static declarations - public static final String[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have a problem just in the line 5

**`public static final String[] CREATIVE_SDK_SCOPES = { "email", "profile", "address" };`**

> Inner classes cannot have static declarations

```
 public final class Keys {
    public static final String CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxx";
    public static final String CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxx";
    public static final String CREATIVE_SDK_REDIRECT_URI = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    public static final String[] CREATIVE_SDK_SCOPES = { "email", "profile", "address" };
  }
  private static final String CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_ID = Keys.CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_ID;
  private static final String CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_SECRET = Keys.CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_SECRET;
  private static final String CREATIVE_SDK_REDIRECT_URI = Keys.CREATIVE_SDK_REDIRECT_URI;
  private static final String[] CREATIVE_SDK_SCOPES = Keys.CREATIVE_SDK_SCOPES;
```

[image: inner classes cannot have static declarations]

Can you explain what does it mean and how to resolve it?

Comment: Declare the class Keys as static too.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'd say don't even bother with the `Keys` class.  Just give the values of all these constants directly in the outer class, and make them `public` there.

Answer (score 3):

> because an inner class is associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

You have to use a static nested class instead.

```
public static final class Keys {
```

See [Why can't inner classes declare static members?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8554813/1916449)